# TOC in output: html_document of R markdown

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

Table of Contents (TOC) options in the metadata section of R markdown do not work. Here is a MWE. It does not produce a TOC. How can I fix it?

```
---
title: "My Study"
author: "My Name"
date: "February 4, 2016"
output: html_document
toc: true
toc_depth: 2
toc_float: true
---

# Section 1. Executive
# Section 2. Introduction
# Section 3. Conclusion
```

Answer (score 4):

The [rmarkdown documentation](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html) specifies that `toc` options should be nested in the output format in the yaml front matter. The following code produces the expected output:

```
---
title: "My Study"
author: "My Name"
date: "February 4, 2016"
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 2
    toc_float: true
---
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, SCOA Really appreciate your help.  I also noticed that I missed " : " after the html_document  Maybe that is the reason that I did not get the desired result and it has nothing to do with indent/nested, etc; agree?

Comment: the column is part of the proper yaml syntax, and so is the indentation. That's what I meant by nested, sorry if that wasn't clear