# Why i cannot set toc in my rmarkdown? I tried setting toc: true but an error pops up. Anyone has any idea how to resolve this?

Tags: r-markdown

---

### title: "XXX Report"
output:
html_document:
toc:true

Error in eval(xfun::parse_only(name)) : object 'toc' not found
Calls:  ... create_output_format -> create_output_format_function -> eval -> eval
Execution halted

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TOC in output: html\_document of R markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35234933/toc-in-output-html-document-of-r-markdown)

Comment: Omg!! I realised you need to add a space between the : and true. So toc:true will not work but toc : true will work